# How to increment number with current year + character string?

Tags: vb.net

```
  Public Sub incrPR()
    Dim curValue As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim yr As String = Now.Year.ToString()
    Dim txt As String = "PR"
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Select MAX(SpecialOrderNo) FROM SpecialOrder", con)
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
            result = "000"
        End If

        Int32.TryParse(result, curValue)
        curValue += 1
        result = curValue.ToString("D3") + "-" + yr + "-" + txt
        txtno.Text = result
    End Using
End Sub
```

Expected output:

001-2018-PR
002-2018-PR
003-2018-PR

Comment: what is your current result?

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but at a guess, the problem is you're not saving the change back to the database table.

Comment: 001-2018-PR will save after that the 001 is not increasing. :(

Comment: That would be because you are saving the text value but you're not saving the number back to `SpecialOrderNo`.  If you expect `MAX(SpecialOrderNo)` to return a different value then you have to save a new, larger value to that column with each new record.  If you save "001-2018-PR" to some other column but don't save 1 to `SpecialOrderNo` then of course the max value won't change.

Comment: What columns do you have in your `SpecialOrder` table?  Is one storing the numerical value and another the text value?  Personally, I'd suggest that you should be storing the sequential numerical value in one column and the year in another and let the text value be built from those on demand.  You can do that in the application and/or in the database.

Comment: its only 1 column for increment number then continued by current year and character string. I tried character string 1st then the increment number and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific reason that you're not seeing the behaviour you want is here:

```
Int32.TryParse(result, curValue)
```

If `result` is "001-2018-PR" then `TryParse` will fail, i.e. return `False`, and that means that `curValue` will be zero.  That means that you are going to get zero EVERY time.  If you want to parse the first part of the text then do that rather than parsing the whole thing, e.g.

```
Int32.TryParse(result.Split("-"c)(0), curValue)
```

I would change things significantly but that will fix your immediate issue.